# Acces denied - obtain properties of file?

Tags: java, file-io, properties, access-denied

I'm running a program to list info of all files stored in folder.

I want to obtain properties of a file (the most important for me is file size, but i would like to get also other properties, like date of modification, etc.).

My problem is when I get to the file which is actually used by another program, I can't get `BasicFileAtrributtes` of file. I've tried to use `File`, `URL`, `RandomFileAcces`, but all of these requiese to open a file, and throw Exception like:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\pagefile.sys (Access is denied)`

Is there any option in java to obtain this properties? I prefer not to use any extra libraries, to keep small size of the application.

App is based on java JRE7.

I'm using `java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor` to visit all the files.
Here is fragment of my code, where I got the error:

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc){
    FileInfo temp=new FileInfo(new FileInfo().repairName(file.toString()));
    temp.isLeaf=true;
    temp.fName=temp.fName.replace(strIn, "");
    File fis=null;
    try {
            fis=new File(file.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            if(fis.exists())
                System.out.println("exists");
            if(fis.isFile())
                System.out.println("isFile");
            System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            temp.fSize=new BigInteger(new Long(fis.length()).toString());     
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    node.add(temp, true);

    FileListCreator.jProgressBar.setValue(++count);
    return CONTINUE;        
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? Perhaps you're accidentally trying to write to read only files.

Comment: Try to call `fis.exists();` and `fis.isFile();` after `fis` initialization. Do they both return `true`?

Comment: @MockerTim: nope, they both return false. I don't have problem with other system protected files (like ntldr), but this one can't be resolved to regular file. I can see the size and properties of file through the Total Commander.

Comment: Print the `file.toString()` value to `System.out`. Does it has the right file path? Add the result to your post.

Comment: right, it returned me null. I repaired `fis=new File(file.toString)` to `fis=new File(file.toAbsolutePath().toString());`, `file.toAbsolutePath().toString()` returns me `C:\pagefile.sys`. but the result length is still 0.

Comment: What are the meanings of `fis.exists()` and `fis.isFile()` now? Does your code prints *exists* and *isFile* strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method [java.io.File.exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) returns false, and the file `C:\pagefile.sys` exists in your file system, you specified the incorrect file path then.

The following code works on my machine:

```
package q10025482;

import java.io.File;

public class TestFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "C:/System Volume Information";//"C:/pagefile.sys"
        File file = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println("\nFile " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " info:");
        System.out.println("Exists: " + file.exists());
        System.out.println("Is file: " + file.isFile());
        System.out.println("Is dir: " + file.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("Length: " + file.length());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is the result output:

```
File C:\System Volume Information info:
Exists: true
Is file: false
Is dir: true
Length: 24576
```

Comment: path is correct, the file exists on my HDD. I've got only problem with system protected files (with C:\pagefile.sys, and floder "System Volume Information"). other files can be accessed now (even files used by another program). Windows is blocking me any option to see this folder, so I'm thinking now, that is this possible in java.

Comment: @filipbe Does `fis.exists()` returns `true` now? If not. Try to execute the code provided by [Guillaume Polet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/928711/guillaume-polet) in a separate program. If it works then the most probable reason is the logical mistake somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine for me:

```
File temp = new File("c:\\pagefile.sys");
System.err.println(temp.length());
System.err.println(temp.lastModified());
```

Comment: it prints for me only "0". i want to obtain also the size of file which is used by another program (like some .xls file used by Excel).